# Why did Mycroft have to break into a facility that he has authority over?

Tags: plot-explanation, sherlock

In *The Final Problem*, Sherlock, John and Mycroft trick their way into the facility at Sherrinford. Once captured, Mycroft reveals himself and begins to demand an account of events from the governor.

Since the whole facility is accountable to Mycroft anyway, why does he have to trick his way into Sherrinford?